# How to map private use characters in symbol font (introduced by adobe) to standard unicode symbols?

Tags: java, unicode

I have created a function which gets an encoded string (possibly UTF-16 not sure) which represents 'belong to' in maths, this symbol consists of two unicde characters u+f0ce and u+f020. But when showing the string to user I am getting : "" which is only the first part of unicode. 
The program is below:

```
String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\uF0CE\\uF020");
```

The above code works for single unicode like \uF0CE only but not combined. Can you please help to find what am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: You can see all [Mathematical Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode). Don't see your character listed there.

Comment: I guess you guys are correct, I need to fix my input. I am getting input from XWPFDocument.XWPFparagraph.XWPFRun so I guess I should explore more about XWPFdocument. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the help. I found a solution to the problem. The Private use characters are a part of Symbol fonts, by adobe. To map these symbols to unicode use the table given in this [unicode](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt) page. Hope this helps. 
Can any of the senior members (having enough reputation to edit the subject of the discussion) please change the title of the post to something like "How to map private use characters in symbol font (introduced by adobe) to standard unicode symbols" ? It might help somebody else.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

U+F0CE and U+F020 are two private-use characters. There is no standard meaning for them in Unicode, but whatever they mean, they are separate. You need to fix your data, or at least find out what the source means by these characters.

Comment: I am no expert in unicode but isnt the first part, the surrogate and second part the lead, used in UTF-16?

Comment: Characters which require two `char` must start with `\uD800` to `\uDBFF` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF

Comment: Lead surrogates are in the range 0xD800..0xDBFF and trail surrogates are in the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF. What you have there are not surrogates.

Comment: So the input I am getting is not UTF-16 but two utf-8 strings?

Comment: No. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 ; UTF-16 is a series of 16-bit code units, where the most common characters are encoded as one 16-bit code units, but rarer characters take two 16-bit code units. You have characters in the Private Use that is in the BMP, that is the area where characters only take one 16-bit code unit.

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty Those are not surrogate code points, therefore you have two separate characters, not a surrogate pair. The data is still UTF-16 though.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/private_use_area.html, those code points are private, and are only defined Microsoft's Symbol font:

   61646   F0CE    Symbol

(Looks like ∈)

So you are being supplied dodgy data, probably from something that was originally produced using Symbol fonts. You should probably map the code points to the modern unicode equivalents from here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_operators/list.htm  (e.g. F0CE -> U+2208)

Comment: The input to my function is not in my control so I guess the input my function getting is wrong?